# how to find users error?

Tags: c#

Hi
is there any quick way to find users error with my software , so if a user find an error , he will easily send to me ?

Answer (score 5):

There are many ways

1-Tell your user to call you 24x7 through 365 days

2- If you use any Chatting software , add your user to your favriot list.

3-Give your email address to send you an email.

4- Give your home address sothat if user passes by to tell you errors

4- Write code to automatically collecting user errors and email as Microsoft usually did.

Answer (score 0):

Have a read of this:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/architecture/exceptionbestpractices.aspx

A compilation of exception best practises...